# CKEditor event for "all content loaded and displayed"?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to do this:

```
editor.window.$.scrollTo(0, val);
```

But it doesn't seem to work unless I wrap it in a setTimeout.

Any idea if there's a way to determine when things are really ready to go?  I've tried the instanceReady and loaded events, as well as jQuery's ready(), but all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was quick, I finally found the right thing to google for.

The setData() method accepts a callback, and I was able to use that to do what I needed.

Comment: please provide some details how you checked that all content is loaded and displayed